# How to register my code as a plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I have created a plugin. Now I want to use it inside of my code, but I don't know how to add it. I have seen things about actions and filters and how to use them, but all of these aren't very clear to me on where to use them.

```
/* Constructor for setting values to the propeties. Make sure to select the right breakpoint with the right image*/
public function __construct($imgPath, $landscapeSelectors, $portraitSelectors, $figureClass, $landscapeBreakpoints, $portraitBreakpoints) {
    $this->setImgPath($imgPath);
    $this->setLandscapeSelectors($landscapeSelectors);
    $this->setPortraitSelectors($portraitSelectors);
    $this->setFigureClass($figureClass);
    $this->setLandscapeBreakpoints($landscapeBreakpoints);
    $this->setPortraitBreakpoints($portraitBreakpoints);
}

/* The picture element is build inside here */
public function createHeroImage() {
    /* Set the base of the figure */
    $this->setHeroImage("<figure style='margin-bottom: -7px;' class='".$this->getFigureClass()['figure']."'>
                                <picture class='".$this->getFigureClass()['figure-div']."'>
                        ");

    $this->landscapeImage();

    $this->portraitImage();

    $this->setHeroImage($this->getHeroImage() . "<img id='hero-image' style='object-fit: cover; height: calc((16 / 9) * 100%)' alt='".$this->getImgPath()['landscapeImage']['alt']."' src='".$this->getImgPath()['portraitImage']['sizes'][$this->getLandscapeSelectors()[0]]."'>");

    $this->setHeroImage($this->getHeroImage() . "</picture>
                                            </figure>");

    return $this->getHeroImage();
}
```

I want to use my plugin on multiple locations. Every location use a slightly different set of parameters for the constructor.So if there is anyone who can give me a clear answer on this.

The code below this bit of text is one of the locations I want to make use of the plugin:

```
if( get_row_layout() == '1_kolom' ): ?>

            <div class="wrapper" style="
                    <?php if( get_sub_field( 'achtergrondkleur' ) ) : ?>
                        background-color: <?php the_sub_field('achtergrondkleur'); ?>;
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if( get_sub_field( 'tekstkleur' ) ) : ?>
                        color: <?php the_sub_field('tekstkleur'); ?>;
                        border-color: <?php the_sub_field('tekstkleur'); ?>;
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if( get_sub_field( 'center' ) ) : ?>
                        text-align: center;
                    <?php endif; ?>
                ">

                <?php if( get_sub_field( 'achtergrondafbeelding' ) ) : 
                                    $section_background_image_landscape = get_sub_field( 'achtergrondafbeelding' );
                                    $section_background_image_portrait = get_sub_field( 'achtergrondafbeelding_staand' );
                                ?>
                //Right here where I initialize the class I want to use the plugin.
                <?php $images = new HayonaResponsiveImages(array('portraitImage' => $section_background_image_portrait, 'landscapeImage' => $section_background_image_landscape), array( 'wrapper-1-col-l' , 'wrapper-1-col-m' ), array( 'wrapper-1-col-s' ) ,  array('figure' => 'wrapper__figure', 'figure-div' => 'wrapper__figure__content'), array( 1024 , 768 ), array( 0 )); ?>
                <?php echo $images->createHeroImage(); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if(get_sub_field('donkere_laag') ) : ?>
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if( get_sub_field( 'achtergrondafbeelding' ) ) : ?>
                <div class="wrapper__content">
                <?php else : ?>
                <div class="wrapper__content" style="position: relative">
                <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="columns">
                            <div class="column1-1">

                                <?php the_sub_field('kolom_1'); ?>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Have you read any of the documentation?

Comment: Yes I have read the documentation on add_action, but I am not so sure on where to use them because I am new to wordpress plugin development.

Comment: Start here https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/

Comment: not very clear where you want to use your plugin, can you add a comment to the code to point out where you're using your class

Comment: I have add a line of comment  where I point out where I want to use the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as it stands your code will not be executed regardless of whether you add it to your functions.php file or you register it as a stand-alone plugin as it makes no call to any of its functions using a WordPress  [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/).

In order for your code to be recognised as a plugin, there are some [preliminaries](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/) that you need to follow, namely create a sub-folder in your /wp-content/plugins/ folder installation, save your code in a file and add a header to it.

1. Create a sub-folder, let's call it `my-first-plugin`,
2. save your code in a file called `my-first-plugin.php` in that sub-folder, and add the following header to it,

   `/*
   Plugin Name:  My First Plugin
   Plugin URI:   https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/
   Description:  Basic WordPress Plugin Header Comment
   Version:      1.0
   Author:       You Name Here
   Author URI:   https://developer.wordpress.org/
   License:      GPL2
   License URI:  https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
   Text Domain:  my-first-plugin
   */`
3. At the bottom of your file you can then insert the following code to [register](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/activation-deactivation-hooks/) your plugin,

   `register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_my_first_plugin' );
   function activate_my_first_plugin(){
     new My_Class();
   }`

this will activate your plugin and create a My_Class object when your plugin is activated in the dashboard.

So in Summary, this is what your file will look like,

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:  My First Plugin
Plugin URI:   https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/
Description:  Basic WordPress Plugin Header Comment
Version:      1.0
Author:       You Name Here
Author URI:   https://developer.wordpress.org/
License:      GPL2
License URI:  https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain:  my-first-plugin
*/

Class My_Class{

/* Constructor for setting values to the propeties. Make sure to select the right breakpoint with the right image*/
public function __construct($imgPath, $landscapeSelectors, $portraitSelectors, $figureClass, $landscapeBreakpoints, $portraitBreakpoints) {
    $this->setImgPath($imgPath);
    $this->setLandscapeSelectors($landscapeSelectors);
    $this->setPortraitSelectors($portraitSelectors);
    $this->setFigureClass($figureClass);
    $this->setLandscapeBreakpoints($landscapeBreakpoints);
    $this->setPortraitBreakpoints($portraitBreakpoints);
}

/* The picture element is build inside here */
public function createHeroImage() {
    /* Set the base of the figure */
    $this->setHeroImage("<figure style='margin-bottom: -7px;' class='".$this->getFigureClass()['figure']."'>
                                <picture class='".$this->getFigureClass()['figure-div']."'>
                        ");

    $this->landscapeImage();

    $this->portraitImage();

    $this->setHeroImage($this->getHeroImage() . "<img id='hero-image' style='object-fit: cover; height: calc((16 / 9) * 100%)' alt='".$this->getImgPath()['landscapeImage']['alt']."' src='".$this->getImgPath()['portraitImage']['sizes'][$this->getLandscapeSelectors()[0]]."'>");

    $this->setHeroImage($this->getHeroImage() . "</picture>
                                            </figure>");

    return $this->getHeroImage();
}
} //ebd My_Class

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_my_first_plugin' );
function activate_my_first_plugin(){
  new My_Class();
}
```

NOTE:

1. I wrapped your code in My_Class declaration, I am assuming you are creating a [php class](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php), since your code exposes a constructor.
2. Your constructor expects multiple parameters which are not available at the time of plugin activation, the common practice is to register your method calls with various WordPress Hooks  inside the constructor. Hence you need to now understand at what point in the WordPress [execution cycle](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) you want your code to run.  As you have not explained this clearly, I cannot help you any further.  You'll need to do something like,

   public function __construct(){
     add_action('init', array($this, 'initialise'));
     add_action(some-other-hook, array($this, call-my-method));
   }

   public function initialise(){
     //method called when a front-page request initialises.
   }
3. Note that you need to wrap your method calls in an array along with your class instance, `array($this, method-call)`, in order for the hook to call the method in your current instance.

Comment: ok, so how do you actually initialise your class construct?  These parameters come from your theme files I presume, but do you get them from a specific post or page object during the request cycle?

Comment: Indeed they are from my theme files. The $imgPath is an array that contains 2 values, 1 landscape image and 1 portrait image. These com from the page where they are added to a post type. The other parameters were all added when you would initialize them, not inside of a page editor in wp. I will show some more code of a location where I want to call plugin.

Comment: so you are going to need to hook your method calls to those actions which give you access to the post type where those parameters can be extracted (for example [the_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/the_post) action), setup all your parameters as class attributes and then access them through static methods or function calls which have access to your class instance.

Comment: I will give it a shot. I am new to the whole plugin devolping thing. I have a question about the extracting the parameters. Because in the first way of setting parameters I just wrote them like this: <?php $images = new HayonaResponsiveImages(array('portraitImage' => $section_background_image_portrait, 'landscapeImage' => $section_background_image_landscape), array( 'wrapper-1-col-l' , 'wrapper-1-col-m' ), array( 'wrapper-1-col-s' ) ,  array('figure' => 'wrapper__figure', 'figure-div' => 'wrapper__figure__content'), array( 1024 , 768 ), array( 0 )); ?>.

Comment: The first array is only filled with data from the website. All the other values I wrote down myself.

Comment: sure you can pass multiple parameters through an array, that's not an issue.  If you're new to plugin development, I really recommend that you download a simple plugin that accomplishes something similar to what you are trying to do, and that you study the code to see and understand how it works.  It is the best teacher!

Comment: sure, no worries :)